# use saved variable in cookie with php

Tags: javascript, php

For last two weeks I was working on saving a page id in cookies and then retrieve it in some other page.

Finally I solved it but now I have some other problem I want to use this id (the one I saved in cookie and retrieve it) in my php code .

I know javascript is client side code and php is server side code but I have to do this. Please help me out with this.

This is my javascript code which is working great and I get the saved id with this line "+value.favoriteid+"

```js
<script>
   /*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
    var faves = new Array();
$(function(){
    var favID;
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

 var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var favID = (pair[0]=='ID' ? pair[1] :1)
//alert(favID);
 }
 $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(){
    var fav = {'favoriteid':favID};
    faves.push(fav);
 var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
    createCookie('favespages', stringified);
    location.reload();
 });
  var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
    if(myfaves){
    faves = myfaves;
    } else {
    faves = new Array();
    }
    $.each(myfaves,function(index,value){
      var element = '<li class="'+index+'"><h4>'+value.favoriteid+'</h4>   ';
      $('#appendfavs').append(element);
    });

});
 </script>
```

Comment: try `print_r($_COOKIE)` also have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: Cookies are stored in client and sended to server. So you can play with the same cookies in javascript and in PHP, but you need to make a distinguish between server and client when you are developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read cookie on `php` side it is easiest thing after you set them by `js`.

> Any cookies sent to you from the client will automatically be included
>   into a $_COOKIE auto-global array if variables_order contains "C". If
>   you wish to assign multiple values to a single cookie, just add [] to
>   the cookie name.
>   Depending on register_globals, regular PHP variables can be created
>   from cookies

**Here php are some examples:**

```
<?php 
echo $_COOKIE["your cookie name"];
?>

<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

> It's not recommended to rely on them as this
>   feature is often turned off for the sake of security.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: hi thank you for your answering your code is working but i have a problem with it. i save page id and page url in cookie thus when i use your code it gives me like this:
`[{"favoriteid":"6","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=6"}]`

Comment: thank you. code  is working but i have a problem with it, assume i save multiple pages in my cookie when i `echo $_COOKIE["your cookie name"];`
it will give me

Comment: `[{"favoriteid":"8","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=8"},{"favoriteid":"7","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=7"}]`

Comment: and if i use the code which give me only the id number i will always have first one "8". how can i save both of them. i think i have to use array but how?

Comment: @user6362236 try this one https://eval.in/605022  . It shows how to get ids

Comment: thank u man it is working geat i used ths part `echo  $value['favoriteid']."\n";` and it gives me the id's.

Comment: excuse me for asking a lot of question but i have another one as i said in question i want to use this id's in this line
`$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = *here*");`

Comment: @user6362236 remove ."\n"

Comment: how can i do this. i mean $value['favoriteid']."\n"; gives me an array of id's how can put them in above line one by one

Comment: select as answer if it helper you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117300/discussion-between-user6362236-and--).

Answer (score 1):

If you already managed to save to cookie in javascript, then it should be no problem to retrive it in PHP, just use `$_COOKIE["COKKIE_NAME"]` (Where you ofcourse change COOKIE_NAME, to the name of the cookie you saved in JS)..

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php for more examples.

Comment: hi thank you for your answering your code is working but i have a problem with it. i save page id and page url in cookie thus when i use your code it gives me like this:
`[{"favoriteid":"6","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=6"}]`
what can i do to just show me the id number: 6

Comment: Okay, so what you have stored is a JSON value, what you can do is use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). That will then turn it into a usable PHP variable.

Comment: i did not get it could u please explain a little more or make a simple code thanks

Comment: Try This: `$data = json_decode($_COOKIE['name of your cookie']);

echo $data[0]->favoriteid;`

Comment: thank you for your helping. i want to use this id in this line 
`$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = *here*");`
when i replace `$data[0]->favoriteid` there it did not give me any result

Comment: thank you. code is working but i have a problem with it, assume i save multiple pages in my cookie when i echo $_COOKIE["your cookie name"]; it will give me

Comment: `[{"favoriteid":"8","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=8"},{"favoriteid":‌​"7","url":"http://localhost/viewcookie.php?ID=7"}]`

Comment: and if i use the code which give me only the id number i will always have first one "8". how can i save both of them. i think i have to use array but how?